# How to hide next element if checkbox is checked in jQuery without using IDs

Tags: jquery, html, toggle

Is it possible to click on a check box and execute code that would show/hide the next element of that respective check box?

**EDIT**

Sorry @MattBusche, I forgot about that!

This is what I had previously:

```
$("#elementID").click(function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(this).next().show();
    } else {
        $(this).next().hide();
    }
});
```

The only problem with this is that I had to add an ID to every single one of my checkboxes and hook it up individually in my jQuery code. However, I tried it with classes and found that each checkbox will hide their next respective element. Sorry!

Comment: If you google "check box and execute code that would show/hide the next element" you'll find the answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#checkbox_id").click(function () {
    if ($(this).is(":checked"))) {
        $(this).next().show();
    } else {
        $(this).next().hide();
    }
});
```